# Angular routerLink does not trigger ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routerlink

This is the ngOnInit in the componet.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.locationService.getLocation().subscribe( locations => {
      this.locations = locations;
    });
  }
```

```
<a [routerLink]="['/locations-list']">
```

when I use a `[routerLink]` to navigate to the above component it navigates to the component and load the view, but it does not trigger above **ngOnInit** method. But if I refresh the page it works fine.

Is there any fix for above problem.

Already I used `href` to navigate to pages and with `href` above method works fine always but its very slow. That's why I changes `href` to `[routerLink]`.

This is the component.html that contains the view

```
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table">
                    <thead class=" text-primary">
                      <th>
                        Location Name
                      </th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody *ngIf="locations?.length > 0">
                      <tr *ngFor="let location of locations">
                        <td *ngIf="location.verified != false">
                          {{location.locationName}}
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Try these: ```<a routerLink="/locations-list">``` or ```<a [routerLink]="locations">```

Comment: are you redirecting to the same page ??

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

Comment: @ram12393 not to the same page

Comment: @kashif it's already there

Comment: what is the `locationService` here ?

Comment: @LahiruMirihagoda are you staying on the same component that you want to navigate?

Comment: @AzkarMoulana No

Comment: Can you reproduce this on stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the router param changed, the base route stays the same. So it doesn't trigger the `ngOnInit`. So subscribe to the route event

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.route.params.subscribe(
     params => { 
            // your code
     });
  }
```

Comment: ```ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
    params => { 
      this.locationService.getLocation().subscribe( locations => {
        this.locations = locations;
      });
    });
  } ```  I tried this but it doesn't work. Please tell me above code is correct or wrong.

Comment: is there any errors

Comment: no it work same as before

Answer (score 3):

ngOnInit() is only called once after a component is instantiated, but not when the route changes. You can inject the router and subscribe to it's events or params to get notified about route changes.

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.route.params.subscribe(params: any) => {
       if(params) //your code
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding a debugger; as first line inside ngOnInit() ?

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

```
// on click call this function
    (click)="HyperLink()"
// on ts file 
    HyperLink(){
       window.open('/locations-list');  
   }
```

Comment: It works. But like ```href``` it is slower than ```[routerLink]```

Comment: This is a workaround of a problem, not a real answer to the problem. You are leaving angular lifecycle.